# How does firefox know when an update is available for an extension (plugin)

Tags: firefox, plugins

I am in the process of creating my first firefox extension and am starting to think about deployment.

There is a nice discussion about creating an template [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274639/how-to-create-a-quick-minimal-firefox-extension) and signing the extension [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129920/how-do-you-sign-your-firefox-extensions)

But later down the road ... how does firefox know that an extension has been updated?

Comment: I have seen Firefox printing information to the console about updating extensions, so if you're already using `window.dump` to develop your addon, you might see some output from time to time that lets you know that your extensions are being updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Versioning%2c_Update_and_Compatibility#Automatic_Add-on_Update_Checking) :

> Applications will periodically check
>   for updates to installed add-ons by
>   retrieving the updateURL. The
>   information returned can be used to
>   notify the user of an updated version
>   to the add-on as well as inform the
>   application of new application
>   versions that the add-on is compatible
>   with.

More details about [updateURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install.rdf#updateURL).